multiple errors in production enviroment while working fine in dev
I use Digital Ocean App Platform to run my app...
I receive these error messages =>
node:internal/process/promises:289
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]             ^
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50] 
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50] AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]     at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]     at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7) {
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]   [errors]: [
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]         at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14)
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1676:16) {
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       errno: -111,
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       syscall: 'connect',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       address: '::1',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       port: 5432
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]     },
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]         at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14)
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1676:16) {
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       errno: -111,
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       syscall: 'connect',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       address: '127.0.0.1',
[distware] [2024-04-29 09:12:50]       port: 5432

In dev mode, there is now issues, I'm not sure what to do.
This is some of my index.js
    // Rendering home page (Company's Dashboard)
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
      } else {
        res.render("home.ejs");
      }
    });

    // Compnay routes handling
    import companyRoutes from "./routes/companyRoutes.js";
    app.use("/", companyRoutes);

    // Login for crew member
    app.get("/logincrewmember", (req, res) => {
      res.render("logincrewmember.ejs");
    });

    app.get("/addcrewmember", (req, res) => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render("registercrewmember.ejs");
      } else {
        res.redirect("/logincrewmember");
      }
    });

    app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
      req.logout(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    });

    app.get("/dashboard", async (req, res) => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
          const email = req.user.email;
          const results = await loginCompanyAccount(email);
          const result = results.rows[0];
          if (result) {
            res.render("dashboard.ejs", { result: result });
          } else {
            res.render("dashboard.ejs", { result: "You are not logged in." });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });

    app.get("/dashboardcrewmember", async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.user);
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
          const results = await db.query(
            `SELECT * FROM crew_member WHERE email = $1`,
            [req.user.email]
          );

          const result = results.rows[0];
          if (result) {
            res.render("dashboardcrewmember.ejs", { result: result });
          } else {
            res.render("dashboardcrewmember.ejs", {
              result: "You are not logged in.",
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else {
        res.redirect("/logincrewmember");
      }
    });

    import { getGeocodedAddress } from "./others/externalAPI.js";
    import { createCompanyAccount, loginCompanyAccount } from "./models/company.js";

    app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
      const email = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;
      const officeaddress = req.body.officeaddress;
      try {
        const { latCoords, lngCoords } = await getGeocodedAddress(officeaddress);
        // Register company
        const checkResult = await loginCompanyAccount(email);
        if (checkResult.rows.length > 0) {
          res.redirect("/login");
        } else {
          bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error("Error hashing password:", err);
            } else {
              const user = await createCompanyAccount(
                email,
                hash,
                officeaddress,
                latCoords,
                lngCoords
              );
              req.login(user.rows[0], (err) => {
                res.redirect("/dashboard");
              });
            }
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render("error.ejs", { error: err });
      }
    });

    // Passport - local strategy for company
    passport.use(
      "local",
      new Strategy(async function verify(username, password, cb) {
        try {
          const result = await loginCompanyAccount(username);
          if (result.rows.length > 0) {
            const user = result.rows[0];
            const storedHashedPassword = user.password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, valid) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error("Error comparing passwords:", err);
                return cb(err);
              } else {
                if (valid) {
                  return cb(null, user);
                } else {
                  return cb(null, false);
                }
              }
            });
          } else {
            return cb("User not found");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    );

    // Passport local strategy for crew member
    passport.use(
      "localcrewmember",
      new Strategy(async function verify(username, password, cb) {
        try {
          const result = await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM crew_member WHERE email = $1 ",
            [username]
          );
          if (result.rows.length > 0) {
            const userCrew = result.rows[0];
            const storedHashedPassword = userCrew.password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, valid) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error("Error comparing passwords:", err);
                return cb(err);
              } else {
                if (valid) {
                  return cb(null, userCrew);
                } else {
                  return cb(null, false);
                }
              }
            });
          } else {
            return cb("User not found");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    );

    app.post("/addcrewmember", async (req, res) => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        try {
          const email = req.body.username;
          const password = req.body.password;
          const firstName = req.body.first_name;
          const lastName = req.body.last_name;
          // Register crew member
          const checkResultCrewMember = await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM crew_member WHERE email = $1",
            [email]
          );
          if (checkResultCrewMember.rows.length > 0) {
            res.redirect("/logincrewmember");
          } else {
            bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error("Error hashing password:", err);
              } else {
                const result = await db.query(
                  "INSERT INTO crew_member (email, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *",
                  [email, hash, firstName, lastName]
                );
                const user = result.rows[0];
                req.login(user, (err) => {
                  res.redirect("/dashboard"); // Parse succssful registeration
                });
              }
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.render("error.ejs", { error: err });
        }
      } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });

I tried check async and await but I'm not sure where the problem is.
I even tried to delpoy the app on heroku same issue.
Checked DB connectivity but no luck.
Is there something with the await async that I'm missing?
Thank you for any help.

It seems you are trying to connect to the database located on localhost and the database is not there probably

Thank you Moti. It was .env file problem.
